# Django Redirect 302 0

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-302

I am trying to add messaging functionality to a django website we're building. I looked around and it seems that django-postman would fill all our requirements.

I installed the app using pip and installed all the other required apps described in the quick start. Added the app to the installed apps and the postman urls to my url file. Did a syncdb and migration for the db and in the admin panel now I have all the django-postman tables.

Now I was trying to use the templates in django-postman and by using the url postman_write, the link is correct but I am getting redirected to my landing page and the server returns a 302 0 code.

```
[16/Sep/2014 11:40:28] "GET /messages/write/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
```

Does anyone have any idea of what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Looking at the code on BitBucket, the write view 
    url(r'^write/(?:(?P<recipients>[^/#]+)/)?$', WriteView.as_view(), name='postman_write'), requires recipients. Have you tried adding a recipient at the end of your url to see if that still redirects?

Comment: Yes, tried that as well, still the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You may be redirected because of a login_required restriction.
Don't you have something similar to this?

```
POSTMAN_DISALLOW_ANONYMOUS = True
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

Comment: This should be comment not an answer.